# jQuery on() - how to grab the correct target?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a something like this:

```
<div id="myTop">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a">one</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a">two</a>   
  ...
</div>
```

And I want to change the data-theme on the button click. I've tried this:

```
$('#myTop').on("click", "a", function (event) {
            $(event.target).attr('data-theme', "b");
        });
```

Problem with this approch is that I'm not sure at what part am actually clicking  that might be a span sometimes and a anchor. How could I make sure that I change the theme on only the a tag?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

(Edit: removed the themeing part of this question)

Comment: You are specifying the `selector` parameter of .on() to `"a"` so you will only handle the click event when anchors are clicked. Check [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fHRBe/

JS

```
$('#myTop').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-theme', 'b').trigger('create');
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="myTop">Theme a</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('#myTop').find("a").on("click", function (event) {
            $(this).data('theme', "b");
        });
```

that whay the click event will only fire in the a tags, and you can change the data attr using the data method that jQuery provides.

Edit: I didn't saw your code right, doing

```
$('#ID').on("click", "a", function () {});
```

will fire the events when you click in container with the id passed, and it's an anchor, because you're passing a selector that acts like a filter. More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)